# JBoss-as:deploy does not inject ${buildNumber}

Tags: java, maven, jboss, buildnumber-maven-plugin

I getting this error at 'jboss-as:deploy':

```
[INFO] Building war: E:\git-repos\GUI4Leader\gui4leader\target\gui4leader-SNAPSHOT-0.6.16-12.04.13-08_09.war
[INFO] WEB-INF\web.xml already added, skipping
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< jboss-as-maven-plugin:7.4.Final:deploy (default-cli) @ gui4leader <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- jboss-as-maven-plugin:7.4.Final:deploy (default-cli) @ gui4leader ---
Apr 12, 2013 8:09:34 AM org.xnio.Xnio <clinit>
INFO: XNIO Version 3.0.7.GA
Apr 12, 2013 8:09:34 AM org.xnio.nio.NioXnio <clinit>
INFO: XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.0.7.GA
Apr 12, 2013 8:09:34 AM org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl <clinit>
INFO: JBoss Remoting version 3.2.12.GA
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 31.910s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Apr 12 08:09:37 CEST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 21M/299M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jboss.as.plugins:jboss-as-maven-plugin:7.4.Final:deploy (default-cli) on project gui4leader: Error executing FORCE_DEPLOY: E:\git-repos\GUI4Leader\gui4leader\target\gui4leader-SNAPSHOT-0.6.${buildNumber}-12.04.13-08_09.war (Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

In the pom.xml i have the buildnumber-maven-plugin:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.1</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <phase>validate</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>create</goal>
        </goals>
        </execution>
</executions>
<configuration>
    <doCheck>false</doCheck>
    <doUpdate>true</doUpdate>
    <format>{0,number}</format>
    <items>
        <item>buildNumber0</item>
    </items>
</configuration>
</plugin>
```

and the jboss-as-maven-plugin plugin

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${version.jboss.maven.plugin}</version>
    <configuration>
        <!-- <filename>${project.build.finalName}.${project.packaging}</filename> -->
    <!-- <filename>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.${buildNumber}-${maven.build.timestamp}.${project.packaging}</filename> -->
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I tried all things that that you can find in the comment. But nothing helps.
I think maybe i need to edit the phase of the buildnumber-maven-plugin but im not an expert in maven.
Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: never user build number but why do you have "buildNumber0"?

Comment: If you call a goal of a plugin no lifecycle is running which means the buildNumber plugin will not run. Furthermore the name you've defined **buildNumber0** is not identical to **buildNumber** which you are using.

Comment: I use the ${buildNumber} for the finalName of the exported war. 
The buildNumber0 is to autoincrement with the buildNumber.properties. 

In the exported war everything works the Name of the war includes the buildNumber but the jboss-as Plugin die not know the value of ${buildNumber}

Comment: Try to change the phase of the buildnumber plugin from "validate" to "initialize".

Comment: Same Failure

`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jboss.as.plugins:jboss-as-maven-plugin:7.4.Final:deploy (default-cli) on project gui4leader: Error executing FORCE_DEPLOY: E:\git-repos\GUI4Leader\gui4leader\target\gui4leader-SNAPSHOT-0.6.${buildNumber}.war`

Comment: any solution to this?